# Media query to target both smartphone portrait and landscape at the same time

Tags: html, css, media-queries, stylesheet

There are some styles that I wish to apply to smartphone, both in portrait and in landscape orientation.

Is there a good media query that targets both scenarios? Actually I have to repeat the css with two media queries:

```
.selector {

// smartphone portrait
@media (min-width: 320px}) and (max-width: 512px}) {
    // stuff
}

// smartphone landscape
@media only screen and (device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape) {
    // same stuff
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you create a media query with the min-width being the portrait phone screen width and the max-width being the landscape phone screen width it should cover it all regardless of orientation.

Comment: In that case I think it will target also dekstop with resized browser window. But I will try, thanks